# Can I ask question about how to jailbreak Kindle?

Tags: discussion

I am not much aware of the rules, so I try to ask in meta before asking in main forum: Can I ask question about how to jailbreak Kindle?

Comment: Ebook reader related questions tend to be in a grey area, depending on the context. This one may be considered off-topic, but I'll mark this question as featured to (hopefully) draw more attention to the rest of the community for discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Such a question would really be off-topic. It's not about *ebooks*; it's about a particular use of *an ebook reader* that is not about ebooks per se. In other words, it's really a question about the Kindle hardware and operating system. Any relation to ebooks themselves is secondary, at best.

I would vote to close a question about jailbreaking a reader, for the same reason I closed the question discussed in [Should Kindle Fire questions not about reading ebooks be off-topic?](https://ebooks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147/should-kindle-fire-questions-not-about-reading-ebooks-be-off-topic?rq=1)